# How to make dependable dropdrown from pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

I have 3 table's:

course table:

```
id | course 
---|-----------
1  | Laravel           
---|-----------
2  | PHP         
---|-----------
3  | JS
```

subject table:

```
id | subject
---|-----------
1  | subject 1           
---|-----------
2  | subject 2         
---|-----------
3  | subject 3
```

course_subject (pivot) table:

```
id | course_id | subject_id
---|-----------|------
1  | 1           1
---|-----------|------
2  | 1         | 2
---|-----------|------
3  | 2         | 3
```

Course.php

```
 public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
}
```

Subject.php

```
 public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
}
```

I want to make a dependable dropdown in my Laravel application:
when I will select a course from select box another select box will get the subject name.
i got the subject id but not subject name. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you show me your blade code structure with Controller.

Comment: Do you need something like a real-time show or you ok with show data after page load?